# Enter edit mode when selecting new or next cell

Tags: jupyter-console

When creating a new cell or moving to a cell using keyboard commands, the cell is selected. However it is necessary to mouse click in it in order to start editing it. Is there a way to automatically enter edit mode?

Comment: This mostly occurs when a cell is changed to markup which will keep focus but exits edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in one key: just type 'enter' and you'll enter edit mode.